# How can I get left hand side or right and side of an expression in R

Tags: r, data.table

in the context on `data.table` one can use different ways to specify `on` in joins (see `help("data.table")`), like `c("date == Date", "id")` or `c(date = "Date", "id")` or ...

In this case I am looking how to get left hand side and right hand side of characters vectors that are "eligible" to be passed to `on`

For instance:

`lhs(c("date == Date", "id"))` => `c("date", "id")`

`rhs(c("date <= Date", "id == ID"))` => `c("Date", "ID")`

`lhs(c(date = "Date", "id"))` => `c("date", "id")`

Comment: strsplit, names - should make the job. you need a helper function for that obviously

Comment: ok so nothing idiomatic from the data.table package ?

Answer (score 3):

An ugly hack -

```
lhs <- function(x) {
  x1 <- sapply(strsplit(x, '\\s*[=><]+\\s*'), head, 1)
  x1[names(x1) != ''] <- names(x1)[names(x1) != '']
  unname(x1)
}

lhs(c("date == Date", "id"))
#[1] "date" "id"  

lhs(c(date = "Date", "id"))
#[1] "date" "id"
```

```
rhs <- function(x) {
  x1 <- sapply(strsplit(x, '\\s*[=><]+\\s*'), tail, 1)
  unname(x1)
}
rhs(c("date <= Date", "id == ID"))
#[1] "Date" "ID"  

rhs(c(date = "Date", "id"))
#[1] "Date" "id"  

rhs(c("date == Date", "id"))
#[1] "Date" "id"
```